# While Exporting CSV from Sales > Order Grid, I am getting error - "You cannot define a correlation name 'order' more than once"

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, export, order-grid

When I try to export csv in Sales > Order Grid, I am getting

```
        You cannot define a correlation name 'order' more than once
```

> Trace:
>       #0 /www/Myproject/htdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Select.php(281): Zend_Db_Select->_join('left join', Array, 'order.entity_id...', Array, NULL)
>       #1 /www/Myproject/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Select.php(357): Varien_Db_Select->_join('left join', Array, 'order.entity_id...', Array, NULL)
>       #2 /www/Myproject/htdocs/app/code/local/Abc/OrderType/Model/Observer.php(32): Zend_Db_Select->joinLeft(Array, 'order.entity_id...', Array)
>       #3 /www/Myproject/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1339): Abc_OrderType_Model_Observer->salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
>       #4 /www/Myproject/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1318): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Abc_OrderType_Model_Observer), 'salesOrderGridC...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
>       #5 /www/Myproject/htdocs/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_order_gri...', Array)
>       #6 /www/Myproject/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(590): Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_gri...', Array)
>       #7 /www/Myproject/htdocs/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(565): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->_beforeLoad()
>       #8 /www/Myproject/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(951): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
>       #9 /www/Myproject/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(1011): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_exportIterateCollection('_exportCsvItem', Array)
>       #10 /www/Myproject/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(703): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->getCsvFile()
>       #11 /www/Myproject/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->exportCsvAction()
>       #12 /www/Myproject/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('exportCsv')
>       #13 /www/Myproject/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>       #14 /www/Myproject/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>       #15 /www/Myproject/htdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>       #16 /www/Myproject/htdocs/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')

And my observer method looks like

```
public function salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore($observer) {
        $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
        $select = $collection->getSelect();
        $select->joinLeft(array('order' => $collection->getTable('sales/order'))
                , 'order.entity_id=main_table.entity_id'
                , array('type' => 'type'));
    }
```

Comment: what event are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the event is called multiple times.
Causing your code in observer to change the collection multiple times.

You should set a flag on collection and only inject your change if flag is not set.
Alternatively determine why event is fired multiple times. Determine if that is correct. Maybe you are using the wrong event for your customization.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, event is being called multiple times, thanks man :D

Answer (score 0):

It's because Magento tries to join the same collection with the same alias twice. Trying using order_new as your alias.

Comment: Now getting "You cannot define a correlation name 'order_new' more than once"

Comment: try printing your query and check